# How to fix the missing field error caused due to updating cache using graphql and react?

Tags: reactjs, graphql

i want to fix the missing field error that i get when i update the cache.

what i am trying to do?
I have the label named "count of availabel items" which displays the number and add , delete buttons. so when user clicks add button this count will decrease and clicking delete button will increase the count.

i have two queries one to list items LIST_ITEMS and other to get the count of available items "GET_COUNT".

which are like below with their types and schema..

```
type Count {
    first: Int!,
    second: Int!,
}

type ITEM {
    name: String,
    id: ID!,
}

type Query {
    getCount: Count,
    listItems: [ITEM],
}


export const LIST_ITEMS = gql`
    query ListItems {
       listItems {
           name
           id
       }
    }
`;

 export const GET_COUNT = gql`
    query GetCount {
       getCount {
           first
           second
       }
    }
`;

 function Parent () {
     const { availableCount } = useGetCount();
     const Count = availableCount.first;
     const onAdd = async () => {
         try {
             await createItem({ name: name, Id: some_var.id });
         }
     };
     render = () => {
     return (
         <span>Count of items</span>
         <span>{Count}</span>
         <button onClick={onAdd}>Add</button>
     )
 }
```

Now when the user clicks Add button createItem mutation is called within that we update the cache to update the created item to the list of items and also decrease the value of count from cache.

This is when i get the error "Missing field GetCount in 2"

this value 2 is the value of count meaning if count value displayed is 3 this shows 2. similarly if the count value displayed is 4 this shows 3 in error..

the createItem mutation is like below

```
const createItem = (variables: CreateItemInput) => {
    return mutation({
        variables,
        update: (cache, { data }) => {
            if (data) {
                const ItemsListCacheData: any = cache.readQuery({
                    query: LIST_ITEMS,
            });
            itemsListCacheData.listItems.push(data.createItem);
            cache.writeQuery({ query: LIST_ITEMS, data: itemsListCacheData });
            const countCacheData: any = cache.readQuery({
                query: GET_COUNT,
            });
            cache.writeQuery({
                query: GET_COUNT,
                data:
                    countCacheData.getCount.siteShares - 1, //doing this causes the error
            });
        }
    },
});
```

};

Could someone help me fix this "missing field getCount in 3" considering the value of Count is 4.

Thanks

Comment: write requires object with 2 not nulled fields - see types

Comment: meaning should i add those other two fields second and __typename?